# Cell Offset Resize

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error on this statement. `cell` represents a single cell reference.

```
cell.Offset(0, 3).Resize(0, 5).Value = xPAYE.Range("C5:C9").Value
```

I am trying to copy the range of values simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Resize*, unlike *Offset* cannot have zero for its arguments.